# searching a string using powershell i a web page

Tags: powershell

I need to validate the username and password of this site. When I type invalid password it should check the page for string 'invalid email'. The message fail to login should be displayed. But 'success' is being displayed.? What is the mistake?

```
$url = "https://www.jabong.com/customer/account/login/" 
$cred = Get-Credential #Read credentials
$username = $cred.username
$username = $username.Replace("\", "")
$password = $cred.GetNetworkCredential().password
$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application; 
$ie.visible = $true; 
$ie.navigate($url); 
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) 
{ 
Start-Sleep 1; 

} 
$ie.Document.getElementById("LoginForm_email").value = $username
$ie.Document.getElementByID("LoginForm_password").value=$password
$ie.Document.getElementByID("qa-login-button").Click();
while($ie.busy) {sleep 1}
$webClient = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "PowerShell Script")
$output = $webClient.DownloadString("https://www.jabong.com/customer/account/login/")
if ($output -like "*Invalid mailid*") {
  "login failed"
} else {
  "success"
}
sleep(300)
```

Comment: You code looks like a mix of various snippets you found and put together. While a valid approach in general, it just doesn't work that way. ) What you need is to get Fiddler or Wireshark and analyze how a web browser does auth on this site. It'll probably be a POST request. Then you can use WebClient (or `Invoke-WebRequest` if you have PS 3.0+) to send a similar request. It's all fairly basic stuff to be honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst I generally agree with @Alexander Obersht, you are only one step away from success. By creating `$webClient = new-object System.Net.WebClient` you establish another session to the website, when in fact you should be polling your current session inside `$ie` object.
Try this:

```powershell
$url = "https://www.jabong.com/customer/account/login/" 
$cred = Get-Credential #Read credentials
$username = $cred.username
$username = $username.Replace("\", "")
$password = $cred.GetNetworkCredential().password
$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application; 
$ie.visible = $true; 
$ie.navigate($url); 
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) 
{ 
    Start-Sleep 1; 
} 
$ie.Document.getElementById("LoginForm_email").value = $username
$ie.Document.getElementByID("LoginForm_password").value=$password
$ie.Document.getElementByID("qa-login-button").Click();
while($ie.busy) {sleep 1}
$output = $ie.Document.Body.innerHTML
if ($output -like "*Invalid mail*") {
    "login failed"
} else {
    "success"
}
```

I also changed your match to `Invalid mail`.